# Cross-Domain single sign-on with azure, ACS, Sharepoint 2010, MVC Site, and WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity, acs

I have a SharePoint 2010 site configured to login with ACS. And ACS configured to use my own Identity provider. I also have a MVC web application which is also claims aware, and uses ACS for authentication.
The Idea is to expose certian services from sharepoint, to the MVC site, using the webservice I have build.

[Here is a Drawing of the Idea:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B084s.jpg)

My Idea was That once you log in to the MVC site you could use that SAML token(idenity) to log on to SharePoint(i just pass the SAML Token to the web service, and the service attempts to log in to SharePoint with that token). I was hoping since I configured The Relying Parties(MVC site, SharePoint) in ACS to use the same certificate for signing, it would accept the token even if it was from a different realm. But that isn't the case. So I was wondering how my web service could impersonate the user with the claims I have. I've been doing endless Research, and i'm pretty convinced this just isn't possible. The real question is, if there is a way for SharePoint to trust the tokens I get on my MVC site, without building an entire STS and having SharePoint have a trust relation ship with that. Any Help and ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trusting tokens that were created for MVC or SharePoint, then your webservice is part of that "realm" so it is ok to add that realm as a valid one. The audience uri validation can be changed from config or code. Are you using WCF? Are you using WIF with WCF?

```
<audienceUris>
   <add value="your:sharepoint-and-mvc:realm" />
   <add value="http://webservice" />
</audienceUris>
```

**edit**: reading your question again and the clarification you made, you will have issues with SharePoint, since they have an STS that will do some transformations to the original ACS token and sign it again with its own keys. Meaning that you don't have access to the original ACS token. I see two options here:

- Create your own token before consuming the service (you can use SimpleWebTokens or JsonWebTokens which are more simple to implement and a shared symmetric key).
- Configure your service to trust SAML tokens signed by ACS or SharePoint key as well the audience URIs.

Since this is a REST service I would go with option 1, transform the original token to a JSON web token, resign with your own key and attach the token to the Authorization header.

Here you have an implementation of JsonWebTokens (JWT)
http://nuget.org/packages/JWT

Here is an implementation of SimpleWebTokens
http://nuget.org/packages/netfx-Microsoft.IdentityModel.Swt

You can use JWT also with asymmetric crypto with x509 certs (it is not implemented in that package though)

Comment: i'm using WIF, but only on my MVC site. I don't have any security implemented yet on my my Rest Service, I Suppose I could build that service so that the user also needs to lo gin to that, and try and get a SharePoint trusted token, by configuring that service to trust the SharePoint audienceUris, and then just request that token from ACS. I think thats what you mean right?

Comment: Well i found your Idea's interesting, but one off the problems in my scenario is that I have to use standard SharePoint. I did manage to get it to work though, I now Redirect my Token from ACS to a bouncer service which can either redirect back to SharePoint or my MVC site. This means i can use one toke for both relying parties(actually making it just one relying party). I can now extract the bootstrap token in my MVC site and pass that one to my service which can pass it on to SharePoint. My only real problem with this is, is that I Don't know what kind of security implications this has.

Comment: (comment was to long) It sorta feels a bit hacked, but I can't really find something wrong with it,  so I was wondering what your thoughts where on this

Comment: I didn't follow. How does the bouncer service knows where to redirect? Can you describe the whole http sequence?

Comment: I have my own HRD(Home Realm Discovery) page. and using that I can build my own return URL, which also makes it possible to pass different variables to my return URL. This is how my bouncer Service knows where to redirect too. so this is what happens:                     l. User selects IP on custom HDR page, 2. User Logs-in IP, 3. Redirect To ACS with token (with custom return url with variable set), 4.ACS Creates Token and Redirects to bouncer service, 5. bouncer service extracts bootstraptoken and depending on the variable redirects user to the correct site with the token.

Comment: it's ok as soon as you keep everything under https. But I still fail to see how do you get the original token from SharePoint? Does the bouncer have some kind of webservice? Oh you have some kind of http module on SP that extracts it from a querystring?

Comment: the "bouncer service" is a webapi that is configured with WIF. It receives a token from ACS. It then extracts that token again and sends it the same way as ACS would (with a redirect and the token in the body) to either SharePoint/_trust/ to log in to SharePoint, or to the mvc site. So I don't use the token I get from SharePoint since SharePoint has his own STS and does some transformations which makes that token useless. I just keep on re-using the ACS token, which both the MVC site and SharePoint trust.

Comment: Hmm I still don't see how this is different to not having the bouncer. How do you call the webservice from SharePoint? How do you obtain the original token from SharePoint?

Comment: I don't re-use the SharePoint token, when i call the SharePoint service, I just use the token i got from acs to log in to SharePoint, get the oauth cookie, and use that to make my service calls to SharePoint.